# Modulo operation in monotone complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Given $x\in\Bbb N$, I would like to find $x\bmod N$, where $N$ is composite. For example $N=35$, $x=53$ and $x\bmod N=18$. Is this operation considered monotone in circuit/algebraic complexity language? I also want to have consider $x_1+x_2\bmod N = x_1\bmod N+x_2\bmod N$ and $x_1x_2\bmod N = (x_1\bmod N)(x_2\bmod N)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In circuit complexity, a monotone operation is a function $f$ which is also *monotone*: if $x \leq y$ then $f(x) \leq f(y)$, where $x \leq y$ is a shorthand for $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$. There are many ways to define modulo $N$, but most of them are probably either uninteresting or not monotone. For example, consider the function which is true if the input is divisible by $N$. Then $f(0) = 1$ while $f(1) = 0$, and $0 \leq 1$ no matter what the actual length of the input is.

Comment: ah ic. I aminterested in just residue mod $N$. so residue mod N is a ring which is not ordered and hence the remainder function is non monotone. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on $N$ and on the length of the input. For example if $N = 2$ and the function is defined as true if the input is odd, then mod $N$ is just the LSB and so it's monotone.

Comment: as I mentioned $N$ is composite. I want to find $x \bmod N$ where $x = N^c$ for some constant $c \in \Bbb R^+$.

Comment: I do not see how $x \bmod 2$ is monotone. Say $x_1$ is $5$ and $x_2$ is $6$. Now $x_1 <x_2$. However, $x_1\bmod 2 = 1 > 0 = x_2\bmod 2$. I think I am missing the point here. Thankyou for the help.

Comment: When comparing bit strings, you don't compare them as numbers, but as bit strings: $x \leq y$ if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Monotone_Boolean_function say add mod $2$ is not monotone.

Comment: This is a different function, also known as *parity*. For example, $\mathrm{parity}(5) = 0$ while $5 \pmod{2} = 1$.

Comment: Ok I am almost certainly confused and I am confusing you as well. When I said $\bmod N$, I really wanted to compute the remainder. Sorry for making this a big mess. So in the literature $x \bmod N$ for all composite $N$ and $x \in \Bbb N$ is called parity. Am I correct? Is this function monotone in algebraic complexity?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Parity is a different function than mod. Check out my example: 5 mod 2 equals 1, while parity(5) equals 0. When the output function is not Boolean, in circuit complexity one considers it as several output functions corresponding to the different bits. These are not going to be monotone. In algebraic complexity, you can define a monotone function as one satisfying $f(a) \leq f(b)$ for $a \leq b$ (here $\leq$ is comparison of numbers). This also fails in your case: if $f$ is mod $p$ then consider $a=p-1$ and $b=p$.

Comment: This clarifies my understanding. Thankyou very much for the answer here.